# Mod_rewrite: How to see the variables content?

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, mod-rewrite

Is there way to display the content of mod_rewrite variables like THE_REQUEST or REQUEST_FILENAME using javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done in PHP using the [$_SERVER variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) *if* the mod_rewrite variables have been exported into the Apache environment variables.

In order to export the Apache mod_rewrite variables so it is accessible by PHP via the Apache environmental variables, ensure the Apache VirtualHost contains the configuration below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=API_VERSION:%{API_VERSION},NE]
RewriteRule .* - [E=THE_REQUEST:%{THE_REQUEST},NE]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_FILENAME:%{REQUEST_FILENAME},NE]
RewriteRule .* - [E=IS_SUBREQ:%{IS_SUBREQ},NE]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTPS:%{HTTPS},NE]
```

Once these variables have been exported, PHP can be used to render the mod_rewrite THE_REQUEST and REQUEST_FILENAME variables, or any other Apache environment variables.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['THE_REQUEST'];
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_FILENAME'];
?>
```

Comment: PHP variable $_SERVER doesn't contain mod_rewrite variables.

Comment: @user1420069 PHP doesn't have access to these variables out of the box, but if they are exported in the vhost (and Apache has been reloaded after the vhost modification) then they are accessible. The answer has been updated to reflect this.